# Jersey check JSON body and create differing POJO based on JSON body content

Tags: json, api, post, jersey, jax-rs

Working with client that posts 2 different JSON bodies to the same path. Hoping for Jersey POST that can map the 2 different JSON bodies to POJOs @ the same path:

Initially tried to overload the API endpoint methods like this, but no dice:

```
@POST
@Path("message")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public RumorMessage basicMessage(RumorMessage rumor) {
    System.out.println("basic message: " + rumor);
    return rumor;
}

@POST
@Path("message")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public WantMessage basicMessage(WantMessage want) {
    System.out.println("basic message: " + want);
    return want;
}
```

Example JSON body for the two message types

```
{"Want": {"ABCD-1234-ABCD-1234-ABCD-125A": 3,
      "ABCD-1234-ABCD-1234-ABCD-129B": 5,
      "ABCD-1234-ABCD-1234-ABCD-123C": 10
     } ,
"EndPoint": "https://example.com/gossip/asff3"
}

{"Rumor" : {"MessageID": "ABCD-1234-ABCD-1234-ABCD-1234:5" ,
        "Originator": "Phil",
        "Text": "Hello World!"
        },
"EndPoint": "https://example.com/gossip/13244"
}
```

How do I parse 2 different JSON bodies that POST to the same @Path("message")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common solution for your problem would be to change the client-code and use different paths or media-types for different 'Pojo-types' (yes also media-types is a good solution, see: https://sites.google.com/site/restframework/media-type-design).

But if this is not possible (would be sad, because it smells not very good) you can define **one** resource-method (endpoint) for both types and write some code to identify them.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
//...
@POST
@Path("message")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String basicMessage(String json) throws JSONException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode obj = mapper.readTree(json);
    if(obj.hasNonNull("???")){
        RumorMessage msg = mapper.treeToValue(obj, RumorMessage.class);
        //...
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(msg);
    } else if(obj.hasNonNull("??????")) {
        WantMessage msg = mapper.treeToValue(obj, WantMessage.class);
        //...
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(msg);
    } else {
        throw new BadRequestException();
    }
}
```